# Change in X and Change in Y in Pearson Correlation

Tags: correlation, generalized-linear-model, modeling, ancova

Suppose I have my x variable calculated as Hormone2-Hormone1 where Hormone2 is at a later time point and Hormone1 is earlier - this is true for all subjects and the time points are equally spaced for all subjects (for now). Similarly, my y variable is calculated as Weight2-Weight1. I perform a correlation (essentially a change in hormone predicts a change in weight) -- let's say the results are as follows: r=-0.50, *P*=0.01.

Am I correct in interpreting this as follows: An increase in hormone is associated with a decrease in weight?

How might be other ways to model this (such as an ANCOVA method)? Perhaps it is known heavier people tend to lose more weight compared to leaner subjects -- what does the regression look like for this? Additionally, what are some other considerations? Perhaps I want to control for "time of follow-up" as well. All these actions well "spend" degrees of freedom but I'd like someone to expound on this a little.

Thanks!

Comment: If Age2-Age1 is the same for all subjects you have no variation in the change in age. How are you computing a correlation when variance is 0?

Comment: Apologies, I just made up an example (which in this case does not work). Let's replace age with "change in hormone level".

Comment: I'm not understanding how the variance is assumed to be zero?
Hormones would change for individuals across time and same with weight.

Comment: my apologies, I misread the edited one.

Answer (score 0):

In this specification, *changes* in hormone level would be associated with *changes* in age level. So if I am correct, an increase in the *magnitude* of the change in hormone is associated with a smaller change in weight.